# The update query is successful but num_rows returns error

Tags: php, mysqli

The following is my query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_override_marks` SET final_mark ='$mark', confirmed ='Y' 
        WHERE fk_class_sub_id ='$cls_sub'";
```

When I give:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows;
```

It gives me trying to get property of non-object in **address** but the database is updated.
Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong and how to find number of affected rows?

Comment: `For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`  Open a manual sometimes.

Comment: caution: [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) says your queries are in risk of SQL injection. You should use prepared statements

Comment: This is just a gist of the query. But even this isn't working @Kaddath

Comment: I think your error is from other thing, so tell us from where it is coming.

Comment: saying it just in case, not only i can't guess your actual knowledge level, but more: being a Q&A site, people can copy your code if they are not warned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the number of records get affected. **mysql_affected_rows** returns the number of rows affected by the last `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` or `DELETE` query.

To check the affected rows use

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_override_marks` SET final_mark ='$mark', confirmed ='Y' 
    WHERE fk_class_sub_id ='$cls_sub'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $conn->affected_rows;
```

You can check the manual [mysqli::$affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: what is your question title, please check

Comment: @YashParekh yeah, i have updated my answer, due to calling the property on wrong object you are getting the error

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly mistake but really freaked me out. Keep helping :)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

[`$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) is a property of the class `mysqli` and not `mysqli_result`. So you have to access it in the right way:

```
echo $conn->affected_rows;
```